# Mount NTFS partition as /home with fstab

Tags: arch-linux, fstab, home, ntfs-3g

I am currently installing Arch Linux on a machine which has Windows 10 already installed on it, and I want to use a NTFS partition as /home (because that way, I can easily access my Linux-files from within Windows).

I've tried to install it this way two times by now, but both times it failed (it would boot in recovery mode, with logs saying that the ntfs-drive couldn't be read).

My question is now, what is the correct way to put this drive in `/etc/fstab`? I created the current fstab with `genfstab -U -p /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab` and now I have the following entry for the ntfs-drive:

```
# /dev/sda2 LABEL=LinuxData
UUID=...    /home    ntfs-3g    rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096    0    0
```

I want every user on the system to be able to read, write and execute to /home.

Comment: Try using ntfs as file type.

Answer (score 1):

ntfs-3g is fuse-based, I suspect you can't use it to replace such a vital part of a Linux filesystem.
Instead you could mount it somewhere in your home and put files you need there.

Answer (score 1):

If you use systemd, there should be a way with a .mount unit and a mount script !
See man systedmd.unit and man systemd.mount !

But generally, you'd avoid using ntfs or any microsoft tech on linux because windows and linux just do not work the same way, and ntfs isn't as well supported as other filesystems. Plus, it's less performant

Answer (score 0):

You need disable hibernate file options first.

```
powercfg /h off
```

If you don't do that, the ntfs-3g partition can't be mounted in `/home`,
or can't be mounted in rw mode on startup from Linux. 
Remember, if you format that partition,
you need to update the UUID in the `fstab` file.

Comment: Is that command run in Linux or in Windows?  … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.